# Google Form Script to create new folder based on drop down list and move images to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I would like to create a script that allows me to create folders based on a drop down list of names on the form. Depending on which name is chosen, I wanna be able to automatically transfer the uploaded pictures to that folder. Is that possible? Not a programmer. I was able to get this from the app but I am getting an error:

> TypeError: itemResponses[1].getResponse(...).Foreach is not a function.

This is the script that I found.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "ID GOES HERE";  //  folder ID of the destination folders.
 
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();
 
  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.
 
  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);
 
  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().Foreach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(uploadedImageId).moveTo(folder));
}
```

Comment: It is indeed possible

Comment: @Cooper could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Cooper Not a programmer. I was to get this from the app but I am getting an error. TypeError: itemResponses[1].getResponse(...).Foreach is not a function.  Script that I found is in the description

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add the information in your comment to the body of your question, because it is directly relevant to your issue. Comments can be overlooked. Code can be easier to format (and read) when it is in a question. Also, a sample of relevant data can often help us to better understand what your code is attempting to do.

Comment: Also - I just noticed: You are using `Foreach()` - whereas it should be [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Whether that fixes things depends on what `itemResponses[1].getResponse()` evaluates to. So you may need to also show us what that is - e.g. by using `console.log( itemResponses[1].getResponse() );`.

Comment: It was what @andrewjames stated, the error occurred due to your typo for `forEach()`. I just want to change `uploadedImageId` to `id` since  `uploadedImageId`  is not defined.